# Xamarin.iOS : How to change the annotation pin colour in apple maps

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I want to change the colour of pin. Following is my code to add the pin on map. Thanks in advance. Any kind of help will be appreciated:

```
map.AddAnnotations(new MKPointAnnotation
                    {
                        Title = "Technician's Location",
                        Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(lattitude, longitude)
                    });
```

Comment: Check out the iOS section of the [link](http://motzcod.es/post/158924172147/colored-map-markers-ios-and-android). Unfortunately it only shows how to change between 3 Apple defined colors. There are other example to create your own view floating around though.

Comment: Check out the iOS section of the [link](http://motzcod.es/post/158924172147/colored-map-markers-ios-and-android). Unfortunately it only shows how to change between 3 Apple defined colors. There are other example to create your own view floating around though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pinColor property of MKPinAnnotationView.
This can be added in the delegate method func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, 
    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!

A typical example of what this method can hold is :-

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    return nil
}

let reuseId = "pin"

var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
if pinView == nil {
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView!.animatesDrop = true
    pinView!.pinColor = .Purple          // you can change color here!
}
else {
    pinView!.annotation = annotation
}

return pinView
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But i need to change the colour of pin in Xamarin ios. I am using this following class:                             MKPinAnnotationView view = new MKPinAnnotationView(new NSCoder()); .This gives me NsInvalidArgumentException. Please tell me what to pass in place of NSCoder.